boto3 saves files very slow
I use s3 minio for storing images. My idea is to save original image then convert it to webp and save converted image. I develop my service locally. I use FastAPI.
Ok let's start:
    async def save_s3_original_converted(self, file: UploadFile, path: str, bucket: str):
        time1 = datetime.now()
        
        file_to_convert = deepcopy(await file.read())
        original_file = deepcopy(file)
        extension = original_file.filename.split(".")[-1]
        uuid_name = str(uuid_pkg.uuid1()) + "." + extension
        original_file.filename = uuid_name
        
        time2 = datetime.now()

        url = await s3_client.upload(file=original_file, path=path, bucket=bucket)
        content_type = file.content_type
        content_type = content_type.split("/")
        
        time3 = datetime.now()

        if content_type[0] == "image":
            converted_file = await self.convert(file=file_to_convert, uuid_name=uuid_name)
          
            time4 = datetime.now()

            path = path.replace("originals", "webp")

            url = await s3_client.upload(file=converted_file, path=path, bucket=bucket)
            
            time5 = datetime.now()
       
            return url
        else:
            raise NotImage

It takes 30 seconds to save the image. And almost all this time is between time4 and time5.
self.convert is below:
    async def convert(self, file: UploadFile, uuid_name: uuid_pkg.UUID) -> BytesIO:
        nparr = np.fromstring(file, np.uint8)

        img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        _, buf = cv2.imencode(".webp", img, [cv2.IMWRITE_WEBP_QUALITY, 50])

        img = BytesIO(buf)
    
        file_converted = UploadFile(file=img)

        filename = uuid_name
        filename = filename.split(".")
        filename[-1] = "webp"
        filename = ".".join(filename)
        file_converted.filename = filename

        filename_utf = filename.encode("utf-8")

        file_converted.headers = Headers({
            'content-disposition': f'form-data; name="avatar"; filename="{filename}"; filename*=UTF-8\'\'{filename_utf}',
            'content-type': 'image/webp'
        })

        file_converted.size = img.getbuffer().nbytes

        return file_converted

OK let's see what happens in s3_client.upload:
class S3:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key_id = settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        self.access_key = settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        self.endpoint_url = settings.MINIO_ENDPOINT

    @property
    @cache
    def client(self):
        # region_name = settings.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
        return boto3.client(
            "s3",
            # region_name=region_name,
            aws_access_key_id=self.key_id,
            aws_secret_access_key=self.access_key,
            endpoint_url=self.endpoint_url,
        )

    async def upload(self, *, file: UploadFile, bucket: str, path: str):
        try:
            await asyncio.to_thread(
                self.client.upload_fileobj,
                file.file,
                bucket,
                path + file.filename,
            )
            return self._get_file_url(bucket=bucket, filename=file.filename, path=path)
        except Exception as err:
            logger.error(err)

    def _get_file_url(self, bucket: str, filename: str, path: str) -> str:
        url = f"{settings.AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL}/{bucket}/{path}{filename}"
        return url

if settings.STORAGE_TYPE == "s3":
    s3_client = S3()

I don't see anything interesting here. And there are even two problems:

Original images are saved as empty file

Webp images are saved for 30 seconds.


The first problem is not very important
Do you have any ideas?
